# PHP wont connect to Apache/SQL server

Tags: php, html, apache, form-submit

I'm having a problem with running my PHP code and running my local apache24 server.

In html i have made a `form`,

```
<form method="post" action="./php/submit.php">
                 <div class="submitrow">
                    <div class="col-25">
                        <label for="fname">Altcoin name*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-75">
                        <input type="text" name="altcoinName" placeholder="Ethereum" maxlength="20" required>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="submitrow">
                    <div class="col-25">
                        <label for="fname">Altcoin symbol*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-75">
                        <input type="text"  name="altcoinSymbol" placeholder="ETH" maxlength="5" required>
                    </div>
                </div> 
 </form>
```

When I submit the `form` I want to run this PHP script that sends the data from the `form` into my local SQL server, that im running with apache24 and phpmyadmin. When I "Submit" my `form` in html the PHP code is not getting executed it just appears in my browsers.

```
<?php
        $altcoinName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'altcoinName');
        $altcoinSymbol = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'altcoinSymbol');
        if (!empty($altcoinName)){
        if (!empty($altcoinSymbol)){
            $host = "localhost/phpmyadmin";
            $dbusername = "root";
            $dbpassword = "";
            $dbname = "servertest";

            //create connection
            $conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

            if (mysqli_connect_error()){
                die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());     
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO submit (altcoinName, altcoinSymbol)
                values ('$altcoinName','$altcoinSymbol')";
                if ($conn->query($sql)){
                    echo "New record is inserted succesfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: ". $sql ."<br>". $conn->error;
                }
                $conn->close();
            }

        } else {
            echo "altcoin symbol should not be empty";
            die();
        }

        } else {
            echo "altcoin name should not be empty";
            die();
        }
?>
```

In the CMD I went to apache folder and started the httpd (httpd -k start).
This error is what i got:

```
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

So I searched what port  `0.0.0.0:80` did with  `netstat -a -o`
And it is `LISTENING` .

Does anybody got an Idea what I could have done wrong or how I could fix this?
I would really appreciate that,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should grant execute access in the directory, usually set already in `/var/www/html/`. But if you are using a site inside a your home directory like `/home/username/public_site/` then you need to allow execution of scripts in this directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your apache is running, but PHP isn't, PHP may not be configured to run from apache.

Methodically go through each step here:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

If its a prebuilt Apache/PHP binary, start with step 6 onward to be sure the PHP side is configured.  If in doubt, rebuild the binary :)

Also, while troubleshooting these sorts of things, there are form issues you can encounter, as well as just Apache/PHP configuration issues.  To verify that at the least Apache is configured properly with PHP, put a php_info() test page in your web root.

If that works, and the form submission doesn't, you may have two seperate issues.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

My gut feeling is that you just need to be sure that step 7 is done, but I've been wrong before.  And don't forget, before you test changes, to restart httpd / apache24 each time you make a change to any Apache or PHP file.